# How do I check whether an arbitrary object is 'None' or not?

Tags: python, if-statement

I tried

```
A == None
```

but for example for lists it will start checking all of the elements rather than check if A exists at all or not.

How do I check this? Is it so obvious that no one asks? I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: "for lists it will start checking all of the elements" - no it won't. It'll do that for NumPy arrays, which are very different from lists.

Comment: Using an IDE with a linter like Atom will flag these sort of statements, which might save you time in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for checking if object is None

```
if obj is None: print 'Object is none'
```

Comment: Works! thanks. Will accept in 10 minutes